# Numpy array 'for' loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using a for loop to pull values from 2 arrays and then put them together in a new array. I can get the last row of the array, but not all the rows before it. (I would like to append each row to the same array.) Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
# Array inputs
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
b = np.array([[1, 10, 20, 30], [2, 40, 50, 60], [3, 70, 80, 90]])
```

Note that the a array will be random depending on what file is loaded. So for one file, it might be:

```
([1, 1, 2])
```

And then for another file it might be:

```
([0, 2, 1])
```

So, the a array looks up the first value of the b array and then takes its last 3 values while indexing this action.

From these 2 arrays, I want a new array like this:

```
# ([[0, 10, 20, 30],
#   [1, 40, 50, 60],
#   [2, 70, 80, 90]])
```

Here's my loop:

```
# Loop to put all values in c and d arrays:
for index, value in enumerate(np.nditer(a)):
    c = b[value][1:4]
    d = index
# Stack c and d array into e
e = np.hstack((c, d))
```

But returns this:

```
([2, 70, 80, 90])  # Only last line of loop. 
                   # I wish to get last line and all lines before it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `for` loop, you can copy contents of `b` to `e` then, replace content of `e` of all rows first column ( *using* `e[:,0]`) by `a`:

```
import numpy as np
# Array inputs
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
b = np.array([[1, 10, 20, 30], [2, 40, 50, 60], [3, 70, 80, 90]])
e = np.copy(b)
e[:,0] = a
print(e)
```

Result:

```
[[ 0 10 20 30]
 [ 1 40 50 60]
 [ 2 70 80 90]]
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding.`

Comment: Ah shoot. I don't think it's going to fix the problem. The idea with the a array is that it is using the values in the array to look up the first value in the b array, then storing the latter three values in the b array to be used in the e array.

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly, may be you can update the question with example.

Comment: The idea with the a array is that it will be random, where you will get something like [ 1, 1, 2 ] for one file, and then [ 0, 2, 1 ] for another file. So, the a array looks up the first value of the b array and then takes its last 3 values while indexing this action.

Comment: I think that to get exactly your desired output (that I understand it is: if `a=[1,1,2]`, then `e=[[ 0, 40, 50, 60],
 [ 1, 40, 50, 60],
 [ 2, 70, 80, 90]]`, you should replace `e=np.copy(b)` by `e=b[a]`